# PHP Process Won't Overwrite With Fwrite

Tags: php, fwrite

I have a problem. I've tried this with localhost on my PC and I have checked every single possibility that I can think of, but the problem still exists. So here it is:

When I click on a link "Equip" it links to a .php file.

In that file, it says:

```
<?

$user = username
$character = charactername

$itemtxt = "http://www.intooblivion.neq3.com/$user/$character/stats/inventory/armoury/".$item."_equipped.txt";
$itemfh = fopen($itemtxt, "w");
fwrite($itemfh, "i");
fclose($itemfh);

?>
```

The problem is, it's not actually doing it. I'm checking the file after the process has been done and it's not actually doing as it's told. It's leaving all of the files that I ask it to modify untouched and I'm not sure why.

Edit: If I try to use the whole path with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is just gives me this error:

```
fopen(/home/u542847060/public_html/StealthParanoia/Aetyr/stats/inventory/armoury/ironsword_equipped.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

That's silly, because that's the exact directory of the file.

FIXED: I was derping incredibly hard. My friend (Haden693) helped me to realise that because the ".txt" was in the same place as the ".php" I didn't need to specify the path in the first place. Whoops.

Thanks for all your help, guys, love you.

<3

Comment: You cannot write to an (http-)url. Write to a relative or absolute path on your filesystem.

Comment: Oh. How do I do that? (I've always been bad with paths).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?

$user = username
$character = charactername

$itemtxt = $item."_equipped.txt";
$itemfh = fopen($itemtxt, "w");
fwrite($itemfh, "i");
fclose($itemfh);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify external file.

If file is in local, open that with absolute path.

```
+ abc.php
|
+ db/
|
+── + abc.txt
```

**abc.php**

```
fopen("db/abc.txt", "w");
```

---

## A Server (Objective)

**temp.txt**

> contents

**modify.php**

```
<?php
    $f = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    fwrite($f, $_GET["m"]);
    fclose($f);
?>
```

## B Server (HTML)

**prompt.html**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://**SERVER-A**/modify.php" method="get">
            <input type="text" name="m">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, You just type modification word in input-box, and Submit!

If you want link, following:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://**SERVER-A**/modify.php?m=**word**">Equip</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I was referring to the local disk, I meant that it worked when I used it locally.

Everything that I'm trying to modify is online and I used to absolute path, from the domain name to the end.

Comment: Online file modification is absolutely impossible. If you want to do that, make another .php file using local modification. And you call that .php file remotely.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what I'm looking at. How does this write to an existing file and what do I even do with it?

The idea is that I click a link and the PHP writes to an existing file, I can't do anything with a form.

Thanks anyway, though

Comment: `A Server` means Remote, `B Server` is your html. `Modify.php` and `temp.txt` must be in together, `prompt.html` is not.

Answer (score 0):

check your file permissions first ...

Your file permissions must be 775 or 777 ...

Without proper file permissions you can't edit the files.

Comment: @JordanElliotFinch is it your local file..?

Comment: All the files that I'm trying to use are online and not on my local disk.

Comment: I have tried this and it claims that the file does not exist:

"fopen(/StealthParanoia/Aetyr/stats/inventory/armoury/ironsword_equipped.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"

But it most certainly exists because I'm looking at it in the FTP XD

Comment: ok... First of all check for file existence using file_exists() method,if it returns false try to create file using fopen(), after creating file change the permission using chmod("filename", 755);

Comment: I tried that, and this happened:

Warning: Division by zero in /home/u542847060/public_html/Into Oblivion v2/adventure.php on line 18 Does not exist. The "Does not exist" part was the "if false" part of my if statement.